# Can I move existing drain on the other side of the floor joist?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I'd like to move drain on the left to the side of the joist to accommodate for off-center Schluter shower tray. Is it acceptable to do in current setup?

If not, can I cut shower tray 5" from the side of the drain to accommodate for current position of the drain which 5" from the wall? [Schluter shower drain is 10"](https://sccpublic.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/sys-master/images/h91/hf5/9023923814430/KST965-1525S_web.jpg) from the left side.
[image: 2]

Edit: Proposed solution

[image]

Comment: please add a picture more from the left, showing the entire (P-trap) plumbing at the existing drain. You also have to keep the shower clear of the existing clean-out at the top of the picture, or move it.

Comment: I think the key part of this question is "in current setup".   It should be possible to accommodate your shower trap plus the other small pipe both entering a 3" drain inside one joist bay.  Worst case you may have to cut out the two wyes and reconfigure this.  Start by putting the shower trap where you want it, and build the rest around it.  You can probably also simplify.  Reduce the number of bends, joints, and get rid of the coupler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the drain has a P-trap (no visible in picture), then heads to the bottom of the picture, traverses the joist, and joins the 3in with a "Wye".

So technically you could have the drain on the 3in side, tied in with a "double wye" at the big white "o" drawn.

Or switch the two Wyes, the top wye for shower, bottom wye for that other 2in.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with what I understand from your response. Is my addition accurate?

Comment: @positron yes that's the idea, to bring the drain and all its piping to this side. Might be easiest to start fresh all the way at the bottom of the picture. Or leave the old shower wye and cap it off.

Comment: thank you. I am wondering why plumber who did this work went to trouble to go through the joist and install as he did, instead of going in the bay where main drain pipe is? Perhaps there was a reason for it?